Using UNION ALL with view table
I have table in multiple schemas, the table in all schemas have the same columns number and type so i'm trying to combine all table data into view table using UNION ALL as shown
CREATE VIEW "combined_closure" AS
SELECT * FROM "schema1"."closure"
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM "schema2"."closure"
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM "schema3"."closure";

but using UNION ALL didn't work when inster this table into ArcGIS or QGIS but if i used
CREATE VIEW "combined_closure" AS
SELECT * FROM "schema1"."closure"

which means getting the data from only 1 table and 1 schema the table will work when i insert it into ArcGIS or QGIS, so why when I use UNION ALL the geometry in view table will not work? And what is the best way to combine the data into dynamic table?

Try to explicitly select your column rather than using SELECT * (as a test you may use only a few column)

I did, the same as using Select* no avail

QGIS (and I guess ArcGIS)  needs a column which uniquely identifies your features, so make sure that when you union all, you don't duplicate those ID's.
